# exitcode=216 in my programe without compiling messages

Tags: pascal, freepascal

this is my program, there is no compiler message, but at the runtime it exits, can anyone please help me? What seems to be wrong?
 The problem started after i made it create the file t, so maybe there is sth there that i can't see. Thanks in advance.
 Collapse | Copy Code

```
program MyProgr;

var
  F: text;
  t: Textfile;
  a, count: array of Integer;
  b: Integer;
  i, int: Integer;
  countnums: Integer;
  n, m: String;
  lin, nums: Integer;
  Small, Big: Integer;

procedure DoWhatEver(S: string);
begin
  val(S, int);
  Write(S, '     ');
  for i := Small to Big do
    if (a[i] = int) then
      count[i] := count[i] + 1;
end;

procedure FilltheArray;
begin
  for i := Small to Big do
    a[i] := i + 1;
end;

procedure ProcessString;
var
  Strng, S: string;
  Last, P: Integer;
begin
  readln(F, Strng);
  Last := 0;
  while Last < length(Strng) do
  begin
    P := Last + 1;
    while (P <= length(Strng)) and (Strng[P] <> ' ') do
      inc(P);
    S := copy(Strng, Last + 1, (P - Last - 1));
    DoWhatEver(S);
    Last := P;
  end
end;

procedure ProcessStringA;
var
  Strng: string;
  Last, P: Integer;
begin
  readln(F, Strng);
  Last := 0;
  while Last < length(Strng) do
  begin
    P := Last + 1;
    while (P <= length(Strng)) and (Strng[P] <> ' ') do
      inc(P);
    n := copy(Strng, Last + 1, (P - Last - 1));
    val(n, nums);
    Last := P;
  end
end;

procedure ProcessStringB;
var
  Strng: string;
  Last, P: Integer;
begin
  readln(F, Strng);
  Last := 0;
  while Last < length(Strng) do
  begin
    P := Last + 1;
    while (P <= length(Strng)) and (Strng[P] <> ' ') do
      inc(P);
    m := copy(Strng, Last + 1, (P - Last - 1));
    val(m, lin);
    Last := P;
  end
end;

begin
  assign(F, 'myfile.txt');
  reset(F);
  ProcessStringA;
  Writeln(nums);
  ProcessStringB;
  Writeln(lin);
  setlength(a, nums);
  Small := Low(a);
  Big := High(a);
  for i := Small to Big do
    count[i] := 0;
  FilltheArray;
  while not eof(F) do
    ProcessString;

  for i := Small to Big do
  begin
    if count[i] = 2 then
      countnums := countnums + 1;
  end;
  Close(F);
  assign(t, 'fileout.txt');
  Rewrite(t);
  Writeln(t, countnums);
  Close(t);

end.
```

Comment: What did you change to “made it create the file”?

Comment: i had to print the results, which means the num. of the variables that appear less than one times in the text that the program reads, into it, so i can't avoid doing that. Is there sth wrong with it?

Comment: We need a [Minimal, Complete, Compilable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What lines in your example did you change to “made it create the file”?

Comment: 216 seems to be derefing a nil pointer. why are you  reset(F);? http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/user/userap4.html

Comment: The problem was that i hadn't allocate memo for count, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've declared two dynamic arrays (`count` and `a`).

```
a, count: array of Integer;
```

Neither of them has memory allocated at this point.

You then allocate memory for `a`, and get the low and high indexes for `a`:

```
setlength(a, nums);
Small := Low(a);
Big := High(a);
```

You then loop through those indexes in the `count` array, which has no memory allocated yet (you called `SetLength` on `a` instead):

```
for i := Small to Big do
  count[i] := 0;
```

Accessing memory you haven't yet allocated generates `Runtime error 216`, which is an access violation (in [Delphi](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/delphifatalerrors_xml.html), which raises an `EAccessViolation` if exceptions are enabled) or a general protection fault (in [FreePascal](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/user/userap4.html)).